# Latest TensorFlow on Nvidia Jetson TX1

Tags: tensorflow, nvidia-jetson

I'm currently trying to run **TensorFlow** on [Nvidia's Jetson Tegra TX1](https://developer.nvidia.com/embedded/buy/jetson-tx1) (running Ubuntu 16.04).
On a usual Ubuntu 16.04 the installation of TensorFlow is as easy as `pip install tensorflow`. But due to the TX1's `arm64` (aka `aarch64`) hardware architecture, this is not possible on the TX1.
I managed to install a prebuilt wheel-file of TensorFlow, but I only found some outdated versions:

- This [pip package `tensorflow-aarch64`](https://pypi.org/project/tensorflow-aarch64/) only provides v1.2
- This [Post by JetsonHacks](https://www.jetsonhacks.com/2017/09/22/install-tensorflow-python-nvidia-jetson-tx-dev-kits/) provides v1.3
- This [lherman-cs/tensorflow-aarch64 github repo](https://github.com/lherman-cs/tensorflow-aarch64) provides v1.4

What I am looking for is a more recent version of TensorFlow ready to install. Does anyone have information on that?

(I also tried to build from source, which failed in several errors and takes some hours)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**TensorFlow 1.10**

Nvidia itself suggests officially to use the current build from this repo:
https://github.com/peterlee0127/tensorflow-nvJetson

And I also found another repo providing pre-built wheels:
https://github.com/JasonAtNvidia/JetsonTFBuild